# Having my wrapper div element full height

Tags: html, css

I need to have the `wrapper` div element to be full height and so adjust its height depending on the whole height of the page so no scrollbars are displayed.

My html:

```
<header>
  I am the header and my height is fixed to 40px.
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
  I am the wrapper
</div>
```

My css:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 40px; <-------- this value is fixed 
  background-color: green;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I know the `height: 90%` on the `wrapper` is wrong but I don't know what to do.

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3putthcv/1/

Comment: and you don't want to use any javascript to calculate the window height, then set the wrapper height to `windowHeight - 40`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
#wrapper {
  height: calc(100% - 40px); /* 40px is the header value */
  background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3putthcv/4/)

---

Or `display:table/table-row`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  display: table-row;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
#wrapper {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>I am the header and my height is fixed to 40px.</header>
<div id="wrapper">I am the wrapper</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3putthcv/6/)

Comment: very nice. and it maintains that even when the height of the page changes... I like it!

Comment: @AbdulAhmad yes, `calc()` is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the size based on the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` like this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3putthcv/3/)) (full disclosure, it won't work if the content is [too large](https://jsfiddle.net/3putthcv/5/)):

```
#wrapper {
background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
```